# How to insert rpivotTable to Shiny UI dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I need to generate dynamically user interface in my shiny App. This involves inserting rpivotTable to UI page under some conditions with insertUI. I found that I can successfully do it only ones. After removing the element and inserting it again it do not appear. The issue is with rpivotTable only. All other interface elements like dataTable, actionButton so on work well. Here is the sample code reproducing the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

ui<- fluidPage(title="test page",
  actionButton("A","insert pivot"),
  actionButton("B","remove pivot")
)

server<- function (input, output, session)
{
  ds<-data.frame(a="1",b="2")

  observeEvent(input$A,{
    cat("insert\n")
    insertUI(selector="#B",
             where="afterEnd",
             ui=rpivotTableOutput("C"),
             immediate = T)
    output$C <- renderRpivotTable({ rpivotTable(data = ds) })
  })

  observeEvent(input$B,{
    cat("remove\n")
    removeUI(selector="div#C",immediate = T)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Any advises how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This question was posted also as an issue in rpivotTable GitHub and was answered there with the solution code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

ui<- fluidPage(title="test page",
               actionButton("A","insert pivot"),
               actionButton("B","remove pivot"),
               div(id = 'placeholder') 
)

server<- function (input, output, session)
{
  ds<-data.frame(a="1",b="2")
  inserted <- c()

  observeEvent(input$A, {
    btn <- input$A
    id <- paste0('txt', btn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = div(
        rpivotTable(ds), 
        id = id
      ))
    inserted <<- c(id, inserted)
  })
  observeEvent(input$B, {
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I assume the solution is basically to use new unique Id for each new insertUI.